# Punzi terms and change of basis

Tags: maximum-likelihood, conditional-probability, fitting

I've collected a datasample with both signal and background events to estimate some parameters of interest, $\lambda$, using a unbinned maximum log-likelihood fit.

The signal PDF is conditionaly dependent on some additional per-event measurements, so I include Punzi terms in the fit to accomadate the irriducable differences between the signal and background distributions for these distributions, so my fitted PDF looks like

$$f \cdot P_{\text{Sig}}(x| T, \lambda) \cdot P(T | S) + (1 - f) \cdot P_{\text{Back}}(x) \cdot P(T | B)$$

where $f$ is the fitted signal fraction, $x$ and $T$ are the observables for each event, $P_{\text{Sig}}$ and $P_{\text{Back}}$ are the signal and background PDFs for $x$, and $P(T | S)$ and $P(T | B)$ are the signal and background Punzi terms.

I've now discovered that the true per-event observable is $Q$, with $T = f(Q)$. If I redefine the signal PDF, to include the definition of $f$, and hence fit

$$f \cdot P_{\text{SigNew}}(x| Q, \lambda) \cdot P(Q | S) + (1 - f) \cdot P_{\text{Back}}(x) \cdot P(Q | B)$$

are the results of the fit expected to be identical? Or is there a Jacobian term from the change of basis that I have neglected.

Comment: I was unfamiliar w/ the idea of a "Punzi term". Does this presentation ([pdf](http://www-ekp.physik.uni-karlsruhe.de/~ekptalk/kab06/Punzi/1_kab06_Punzi.pdf)) describe what you have in mind?

Comment: Hi @gung, Yes. That is exactly what I'm describing. It's usually referred to as the Punzi term in particle physics, I'm not sure if there is a more common, mainstream name.

Comment: That may well be perfectly common. I'm just not a particle physicist, & I suspect few here are.

Comment: @gung "Punzi term" is not common.  It seems to be an obscure term used primarily by German-speaking particle physicists.  Andy, you will greatly increase your chances of being understood if you would define your terminology or recast it in more conventional language.